# Cloud Firestore rules issue

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an all app which I can dynamically enter things to a list, which are stored in a database in cloud firestore, each item has a name and a userId. In my App I have all the authentication done, everything works wonderfully, every time I enter something to the list, each item has the userId of the respective user. The problem is that I am in the final stage where I want each user to have their own list, and not be able to access another user's list and vice versa. So I am changing the database rules but i ran into problems. When entering things to my list, these things are added to the database, with their respective name and user id, but they do not appear in the application! It doesn't show me the items in the app, but the items exist in the database.

UPDATE: SOLVED!

Comment: Consider adding an answer if you solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some mistake with your code. According to your code, you trying to access the whole document from the collection `shows` regardless of the user. This will be clearly denied by the firebase security rule. According to rule an user can only access their own data and remember that firebase security rules are not filters.

So the code should be

```
db.collection('shows').where('userId','==',uid_of_the_user)
.orderBy('timestamp').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>...)
```

Comment: Ok so I did that, same issue still happening, probably in code as well. Im really new with firebase so im struggling to implement it to my app :/

Comment: what you have tried? Could you please share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the function `matchesUser()` in the security rule. You are passing an incorrect value `request.resource.data` to the function. Instead of that you have to pass
`resource.data`. The `request.resource.data` variable contains the future state of the document and `resource.data` contains current state of the document.

The code should be

```
allow read: if authed() && matchesUser(resource.data);
```

Comment: I changed it and the same error keeps happening :/